# I removed anaconda and now my python path is messed up. Do you know how to fix it?

Tags: python, environment-variables, anaconda

I downloaded anaconda earlier today to experiment with a library that said I needed it. I ended up removing it, but now my old python installation does not work.

When I look at the environment variables I do notice it says anaconda under path. Does anyone know how to make everything go back to normal?

```
PATH=/Users/spencercooley/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/spencercooley/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/Users/spencercooley/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin:/Users/spencercooley/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/Users/spencercooley/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin
```

Comment: the title is perfect!

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the `/Users/spencercooley/.bashrc` and/or `/Users/spencercooley/.bash_profile` files. One of them likely contains a line like `export PATH=/Users/spencercooley/anaconda/bin:$PATH`, which you can remove. Then, load up a new terminal instance and it should be back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

I banged my head against the wall whole morning on this.
Eventually this is what worked for me:
Anaconda runs a script that edits your

> Blockquote
>   ~/.bash_profile

To revert to your initial python installations, simply remove the anaconda paths prepended on your *~/.bash_profile* by:

1. Run nano *~/.bash_profile* or *vi ~/.bash_profile*.
2. Remove the lines that take the format */home//anaconda3/bin:$PATH*