# How do I use script provided by Anaconda without using the given python?

Tags: python, anaconda

It seems that when I install Anaconda, I can't neither normal python or the python provided with Anaconda, even though Anaconda already in path.

I do realize that Anaconda also come with a python, but it come both with 2.7 and 3.2, but it's kinda scary due to the path conflict that I had earlier.  [It may ended like this, fortunately it goes  normal when I uninstalled it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19698413/i-removed-anaconda-and-now-my-python-path-is-messed-up-do-you-know-how-to-fix-i)

After uninstalling, my plan is to only take the installed library then uninstall Anaconda:

1. Reinstall Anaconda
2. Copy the library (scipy,numpy,etc)
3. Paste it to normal Python2
4. Uninstall Anaconda and its family
5. Hapilly ever after

But this seems not foolproof, is there any better way?

Note: As I mentioned, I know Anaconda have python avaliable too, so my other alternative is to uninstall normal python and just use Anaconda. But again, when I saw they provided two version, I decided to take the way mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Python is getting more complex and installing libraries in a way that they work is becoming more brittle. You can [install `pip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) which will try to download the source code for libraries and compile them for your OS (which might or might not need a C compiler locally installed and working).

Anaconda tries to solve this hazzle by providing a set of working, well maintained libraries which you can install easily using the `conda` tool. When I installed the product last time, it didn't try to install both Python 2 and 3 - you have to select either. It also *asks* whether it should add itself to your path; you can say "no".

But you have to chose between: "I know exactly what I'm doing" - then you're on your own. Or you can say "I don't know enough" and trust some unknown expert to get it right most of the time.

You copy&paste approach might work since I haven't seen a Python library where absolute paths were compiled in. On the other hand, some of those libraries have hundreds of thousands of lines of code. It's hard to say which one of them will break when you start moving things around.